Algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{F}_p$
Let $p \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ be a prime integer, and let $\mathbb{F}_p$ denote the field with $p$ elements. If $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$. It is a known fact that
$$
\overline{\mathbb{F}_p} = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left\{u\in \overline{\mathbb{F}_p} : u^{p^k} = u\right\},
$$
where each set $\left\{u\in \overline{\mathbb{F}_p} : u^{p^k} = u\right\}$ is canonically isomorphic to the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ with $p^k$ elements. In this sense, one can consider $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ as the direct limit of the fields $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$, indexed by $k$ in the directed set $\mathbb{Z}^+$ partially ordered by "divides."
While trying to prove this fact, I came up with an argument that, if true, proves the following:

Let $L$ be an algebraic field extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$. Then
$$
L = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left\{u\in L : u^{p^k} = u\right\}.
$$

My question: is the above assertion true? If so, does that mean every algebraic extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ a direct limit of some subsystem of the fields $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$? If not, is there another classification of algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{F}_p$?
For context, this is the argument I used: let $\alpha\in L$ be given. Since $L$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_p$, $\alpha$ has a minimal polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$. Because $v^{p^k} = v$ for all $v\in \mathbb{F}_p$, it follows from the fact that the characteristic of $L$ is $p$ that
$$
\left[f(x)\right]^{p^k} = f\left(x^{p^k}\right)
$$
for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Therefore, the set $\left\{\alpha^{p^k} : k\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}\right\} \subseteq L$ is contained in the set of roots of $f$ and hence finite.
So, there exist distinct $k_1,k_2\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$ such that $\alpha^{p^{k_1}} = \alpha^{p^{k_2}}$. Assume without loss of generality that $k_2 > k_1$, and fix $k = k_2-k_1$. Considering the polynomial $g(x) = x^{p^{k_1}} - \alpha^{p^{k_1}}\in L[x]$, we find that $\alpha$ and $\alpha^{p^k}$ are both roots of $g$. However,
$$
g(x) = x^{p^{k_1}} - \alpha^{p^{k_1}} = x^{p^{k_1}} + (-1)^{p^{k_1}}\alpha^{p^{k_1}} = x^{p^{k_1}} + (-\alpha)^{p^{k_1}} = (x-\alpha)^{p^{k_1}}
$$
since if $p = 2$, then $-1 = 1$, and if $p > 2$, then $p^{k_1}$ is odd. Therefore, $\alpha = \alpha^{p^k}$, and we are done.
Is my argument correct?

Yes, the assertion $L = \bigcup_{k=1}^{+\infty} \left{u\in L : u^{p^k} = u\right}$ is correct. The ($\supseteq$) is obvious. For the  ($\subseteq$) side, for each $u\in L$, if $F_p(u)$ is an extension of degree $k$ of $F_p$, then $x^{p^k}=x$ for every $x\in F_p(u)$, a fortiori it holds for $u$.
